# com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh 3.6.15 crushes the app

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, pushwoosh

I'm using Intel-XDK to develope an app, I want to implement push notifications.
I am using pushwoosh cordova plugin 3.6.15
After a successful build I install it on my device but the app is crushes.
When I add the plugin but not using it it doesn't crush
This is the code lines I add in order to use the plugin:

```
try {
                if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                    registerPushwooshAndroid();
                } else if (/(iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err.message);
            }


This is the implementation of PushwooshAndroid.js:


/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

function registerPushwooshAndroid() {
    var pushNotification = cordova.require("com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh.PushNotification");

    //set push notifications handler
    document.addEventListener('push-notification',
        function(event) {
            var title = event.notification.title;
            var userData = event.notification.userdata;

            //dump custom data to the console if it exists
            if (typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
                console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
            }

            //and show alert
            alert(title);

            //stopping geopushes
            //pushNotification.stopGeoPushes();
        }
    );

    //initialize Pushwoosh with projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID", appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID". This will trigger all pending push notifications on start.
    pushNotification.onDeviceReady({
        projectid: "My ProjectID",
        pw_appid: "My pw_appid"
    });

    //register for push notifications
    pushNotification.registerDevice(
        function(token) {
            alert(token);
            //callback when pushwoosh is ready
            onPushwooshAndroidInitialized(token);
        },
        function(status) {
            alert("failed to register: " + status);
            console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
        }
    );
}

function onPushwooshAndroidInitialized(pushToken) {
    //output the token to the console
    console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);

    var pushNotification = cordova.require("com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh.PushNotification");

    //if you need push token at a later time you can always get it from Pushwoosh plugin
    pushNotification.getPushToken(
        function(token) {
            console.warn('push token: ' + token);
        }
    );

    //and HWID if you want to communicate with Pushwoosh API
    pushNotification.getPushwooshHWID(
        function(token) {
            console.warn('Pushwoosh HWID: ' + token);
        }
    );

    pushNotification.getTags(
        function(tags) {
            console.warn('tags for the device: ' + JSON.stringify(tags));
        },
        function(error) {
            console.warn('get tags error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    );


    //set multi notificaiton mode
    //pushNotification.setMultiNotificationMode();
    //pushNotification.setEnableLED(true);

    //set single notification mode
    //pushNotification.setSingleNotificationMode();

    //disable sound and vibration
    //pushNotification.setSoundType(1);
    //pushNotification.setVibrateType(1);

    pushNotification.setLightScreenOnNotification(false);

    //setting list tags
    //pushNotification.setTags({"MyTag":["hello", "world"]});

    //settings tags
    pushNotification.setTags({
            deviceName: "hello",
            deviceId: 10
        },
        function(status) {
            console.warn('setTags success');
        },
        function(status) {
            console.warn('setTags failed');
        }
    );

    //Pushwoosh Android specific method that cares for the battery
    //pushNotification.startGeoPushes();
}


Please assist me
I would have sent the APK but I cant becuase its size is 47M
Another thing, I tried the pushwoosh tutorial project and it did not fail, I don't know why
Thanks for your help
```

Comment: I include these js scripts in my index.html code too: <script src="js/app.js"></script>                
    <script src="js/PushwooshAndroid.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PushwooshiOS.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PushwooshWP.js"></script>   
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are adding Pushwoosh XDK plugin as per docs:
http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap

For Intel XDK: Add pushwoosh-intel-xdk-plugin as Third-Party Plugin

Comment: Hi, I added it exactly as in the documentation.. It just not working.
It has to do with the admob plugin, they don't live well together. I need help to implement push notifications via pushwoosh or anything else using intel-xdk and I don't know how

Comment: Probably admob uses old Google Play Services library. Can you attach crash logs of the app as well? It's getting really hard to guess.